# Trigger C# method from JavaScript and send parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to call a C# method from JavaScript and send parameters along with the call. I've done calls to web method but since I can't get to server side controls in static web method, I can't really use it in this case.

I can't do full postback because I need to get Google Map coordinates which in my case I'm accessing them this way, and I'm not able to access them differently:

```
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        bounds = map.getBounds();    
        var latLng = map.getCenter();                
        var latSW = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
        var lngSW = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
        var centerLat = latLng.lat();
        var centerLng = latLng.lng();
```

So now since I want to pass some of these parameters to actual c# function it's ok even if I need to do full server side postback as long as I have the controls in my backend code.

Once on server side I need to populate asp.net repeater control with the dataset, that's the biggest issue why I need to trigger backend method.

```
public void GetData(string latSW, string lngSW, string latNE, string lngNE)
    {
        DataTable dt = this.GetData(latSW, lngSW, latNE, lngNE);
        rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
        rptMarkers.DataBind();
        RepDetails.DataSource = dt;
        RepDetails.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about an ajax call?

Comment: Angel, I think some details are missing because I'm not quite sure when you need to make a full postback and when you don't. It's not clear

Comment: @Leo I would like to do full postback from client side code with parameters. Thanks

Comment: @markpsmith just a normal postback call called by JS

Comment: But you said: ' I can't do full postback'...

Comment: @markpsmith With that I was saying that if I do normal full postback without using JS I'll not be able to get google map coordinates and send them to the server side method because I can access the coordinates only on clientside. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. You can't do a postback (ie form POST) because you've accessed the google coordinates on the client?

Comment: yes correct @markpsmith but I need to somehow pass them to actual c# function, not a webmethod, because I can't populate the server side repeater control in webmethod. Thanks

Comment: If you populated some hidden form fields with the coords, you could do a normal POST.  Would that work for you?

Comment: Can you state the "flow": when that javascript is run, and when you want the postback to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure, from your question, whether you can or can't make a full post back so here's a fun javascript solution

```
function myawesomejavascriptfunction(latsw,lngsw,latne,lngne)
{
 var myawesomeform=document.createElement('form');
 myawesomeform.setAttribute('method','post");
 myawesomeform.setAttribute('action','/myawesomewebendpoint');

 var myawesomelatsw=document.createElement('input');
 myawesomelatsw.setAttribute('type','hidden');
 myawesomelatsw.setAttribute('name','latsw');
 myawesomelatsw.setAttribute('value',latsw);

 var myawesomelngsw=document.createElement('input');
 myawesomelngsw.setAttribute('type','hidden');
 myawesomelngsw.setAttribute('name','lngsw');
 myawesomelngsw.setAttribute('value',lngsw);

 var myawesomelatne=document.createElement('input');
 myawesomelatne.setAttribute('type','hidden');
 myawesomelatne.setAttribute('name','latne');
 myawesomelatne.setAttribute('value',latne);

 var myawesomelngne=document.createElement('input');
 myawesomelngne.setAttribute('type','hidden');
 myawesomelngne.setAttribute('name','lngne');
 myawesomelngne.setAttribute('value',lngne);

 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myawesomeform);
 myawesomeform.submit();
}
```

The endpoint method at `/myawesomewebendpoint` will call the class with the `GetData()` method and pass on the parameters.

It will work, provided I've not got hold of the entirely wrong end of the stick.